# Not able to Create Symbolic Link for Ploty Orca

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, plotly, orca

I am trying to generate a PDF of a report with charts I built with Jupyter notebook and plotly on WSL Ubuntu 18.04. I am following the directions from the Plotly website and github to install the packages however, when trying to create a symbolic link to orca-1.3.0.AppImage I am not getting a path returned. I have tried adding to a new folder to create a new path but nothing has worked. I need this last step so I can get the charts to appear in my report.

Currently the orca-1.3.0.AppImage executable is in my home directory so for example I tried the following:

```
ln -s ~/orca-X.Y.Z-x86_64.AppImage ~/orca
```

and when I run which orca no path comes back. It is my first time doing this. I have tried a few options that I researched before creating this post. Any info will be greatly appricated.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the orca-X.Y.Z-x86_64.AppImag file move it to the /usr/bin folder and run sudo ln -s /usr/bin/orca-X.Y.Z-x86_64.AppImage /usr/bin/orca and it should work.

Comment: I also had to make the orca AppImage executable `chmod +x orca-X.Y.Z-x86_64.AppImage` for this to work per Ploty [docs](https://github.com/plotly/orca)